# How to Increase the product Quantity as well as the Cost simultaneously by using a Input number box. Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
< script >

  var Boys = [{
    name: "Rubix cube",
    Cost: 250,
    image: "Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg",
  }, {
    name: "Drone",
    Cost: 5000,
    image: "Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Aeroplane",
    Cost: 3000,
    image: "Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Cars",
    Cost: 1500,
    image: "Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Rc.Hellio",
    Cost: 1000,
    image: "Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Brown Teddy",
    Cost: 800,
    image: "Pictures/Teddy.jpg"
  }];


var Obj = function(myFunction) {
  this.myNumber = myNumber
}
var x = new Obj("demo");

//var Cost = [250, 50000, 3000, 1500, 1000, 800]; 


var Boys_Toys = "  ";

var images = ["Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg", "Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg", "Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg", "Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg", "Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg", "Pictures/Teddy.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < Boys.length; i++) {

  Boys_Toys += '<div class="card"><h2>' + Boys[i].name + '</h2><img src=' + Boys[i].image + ' style="width:250px" border="3px"><p class="Cost">$ ' + Boys[i].Cost + '</p> <p> <button> Add to cart </button> </p> </div>';
}


console.log(Boys_Toys);

document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = Boys_Toys;




<
/script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>


  <style>
    .card {
      width: 300px;
      height: 450px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .product_image {
      width: 50px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 5px #000000 solid;
    }
  </style>


  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>


  <title>Toy-World.</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#cbc8c8">


  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1">

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    }
  </script>



</body>


<h1 align="Center"> <u>Toy-World</u> </h1>

<div id="cart"></div>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

How to Increase the product Quantity as well as the Cost simultaneously by using a Input number box. Using JavaScript!

For Example:- I purchase an Item form a online store and i decide to buy 5 more of the Product, so using a Input value button i Increase the Quantity. While Increasing the Number of Products Needed the Cost Value Should Add on.{ If cost price if 50$ and i select two the cost amount Should Change to 100$ and So on.}

Comment: You can add this event inside your input box and place your logic inside the function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Comment: There are near infinite ways to do this with different frameworks and libraries. Are you using plain javascript and html? If so can you show us what you've tried so far?
It's much easier to help you if we know what your html structure looks like

Comment: @LiefdeWen . Yes i'm using Plain JavaScript and HTML. Just Edited my Post!.